# Javascript error - Object has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I got the following script shortened :

```
var HTH = HTH || {};

(function() {
    var assetGrouping = function() {
        var self = this;

        this.options = {
            _tmpElement:        '',
            QuantityAssigned:   0,
            qtyInputField:      ''
        };

        this.init = function(options){
            // ...
            this.options.QuantityAssigned = 0;
            jQuery(this.options.qtyInputField).bind('keyup', function(){
                self._tmpElement = jQuery(this);
                self.CalculateQuantityAssigned();
            });

            // ...
        }

        CalculateQuantityAssigned = function(){
            // ...
        }
    }

    HTH.assetGrouping = new assetGrouping();
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    HTH.assetGrouping.init({
        qtyInputField: 'input[name^="at700_group_qty"]'
    });
});
```

The error happen at the following line : `self.CalculateQuantityAssigned();` and the error is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'CalculateQuantityAssigned'`.

I don't understand. Using `this` will fail of course and `self` is working when I want to access `self.options` but not for `self.CalculateQuantityAssigned()`.

Thanks.

Comment: this.CalculateQuantityAssigned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
CalculateQuantityAssigned = function(){
            // ...
}
```

to

```
this.CalculateQuantityAssigned = function(){
            // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh my god... Wow ! I forgot the this... Nice eye, this must be a sign of tiredness. Thanks a lot ! Will accept asap.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {
});  <-- You have a function, but you never execute it!
```

You need to add the `();`

Comment: You are right, `})();`. It is there, just my mitake that I didn't put in the "demo" script above.